# Why does Powershell script variable not save output from invoke-restmethod response?

Tags: vba, io-redirection, powershell-core, rest

everyone.

When I issue the Invoke-RestMethod command, via the PS shell (version 7), the expected output is saved into a variable.

However, when I put the same commands into a PS script, then calling said script using VBA, the same output is not saved into a variable (or into a file).  Why, and what am I missing?

VBA code (snippet):

```
   strCommand = "pwsh -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\....\tpCancelOrder.ps1 " & sCW & " " & sDON & ""

   Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

   WshShellexec = WshShell.Run(strCommand)
```

PS code (snippet from tpCancelOrder.ps1):

```
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod @params -SkipCertificateCheck
```

[Pausing the PS script to see what's being outputted / returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mFA4.png)

So, (from the screenshot) we can see that there is (actually, the same expected) output.

However, the next PS commmands

```
   Write-Output $response.ToString | Set-Content "C:\Users\....\tpCancelOrder.log"

   $response | ConvertTo-Json
```

return NULL.

I've tried various combinations of write-host, write-debug... redirection, out-file, tee-object.... but all to no avail.

From a PS shell, no issues——$response stores/contains the expected output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your screenshot suggests that your actual code calls `$response = Invoke-RestMethod @params -SkipCertificateCheck  | Out-File ...`. Given that `Out-File` produces no output, `$response` is effectively `$null`. Also, the screenshot shows an _error_, which wouldn't be captured in a variable being assigned to.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. i also tried redirection via *>&1 to capture everything(?) to standanrd output, with something like ... *>&1 | Out-File.... and *>&1 | Tee-Object...  and other combinations.  Guess i'll try & focus on other (non *>&1) options.  Btw i also need any error/mesage saved in the same variable.  I suppose *>&1 should have done that?  Double-checking.  Thanks again.